# AppAsset isn't including

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I copied a repository from git and frontend seems to be ok however in the backend I have issues with AppAsset

AppAsset file:

```
<?php

namespace backend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main backend application asset bundle.
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Layouts main.php file I only kept 'Hello world' in h1 to test the css

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use backend\assets\AppAsset;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use common\widgets\Alert;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php $this->registerCsrfMetaTags() ?>
    <?php $this->registerCssFile("@backend/web/css/site.css") ?>
    <?php /*$this->registerCss("body { background: #f00; }") */?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

in the end of web/css/site.css I added the following code:

```
h1{
    background: red;
}
body{
    background: red;
}
```

I feel like the issue might be with AppAssets configuration. Also I'm new to yii and

doesn't work:  `<?php $this->registerCssFile("@web/css/site.css") ?>`
works:  `<?php $this->registerCss("body { background: #f00; }") ?>`

Comment: Did you try to check the generated html code if there are tags for including the css file and what url are they generated with?

Comment: I solved this not long after, the reason is baseurl is set to admin in the backend->config->main->componenets, once removed it, worked fine